# LibVLC# Stream over TCP

Tags: c#, libvlcsharp

I currently have code that returns a valid URI for streaming from an IP Camera. I take that uri and pass it into an object for streaming. Can I configure the objects so they stream over TCP? The VLC application has a setting where I can stream this same URI over TCP so I know the camera has the functionality. When I use the VLC application it just forces RTP over port 554 for a TCP video stream. Currently with this code, it sets up RTSP over 554 and begins streaming RTP over UDP from a different port. What am I missing?

```
Establish Objects 
            _libVLC = new LibVLC();
            _mp = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
            videoView.MediaPlayer = _mp;

////GET local uri//// 

            bool check = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(local_uri.Uri.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);   
            if (check)
            {
                                          
                    _mp.Play(new LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media(_libVLC, local_uri.Uri));
                    check = false;
```

The uri string comes back formatted as
Rtsp://MY-IP

I've tried what a few others have recommended by reformatting it to...
rtsp-tcp://MY-IP
and it doesn't seem to work (or i'm doing it wrong).

////////////////////////////////
Edit: ////////////////////

```
            LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media media = new Media(_libVLC, local_uri.Uri);
            media.AddOption(":rtsp-tcp"); //<---- Is this passing the option correctly. 
            _mp.Play(media);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `"--rtsp-tcp"` as a LibVLC option, or `:rtsp-tcp` as a media option.

See https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

Comment: Thank you! I've attached what I tried on the original post. It doesn't work. Am I doing this correctly? Or at least have the right idea. Watching the wire-shark captures closely when using the VLC application it looks like out of the 4 payloads sent (Options, describe, setup, play) the setup payload is the one that tells it to play TCP. I abandoned attempting something like what you have because I assumed this only affected the "Options" payload. Maybe I was to quick to jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

When you first initialize your VLC object `_libVLC = new LibVLC()`, you can overload the constructor with a string.

Here is the RTSP-TCP option on the VLC Command-Line Help: [RTSP-TCP option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9j2N.png)

You can then initialize your VLC object like so:

```
_libVLC = new LibVLC("--rtsp-tcp")
```

As @cube45 pointed out, you can use the VLC Command-Line help [doc](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) to help you find the options that suits you. A simple *Ctrl + f* followed by your search should help you determine whether or not what you are looking for exists in this library.